# Turn recursive function into iterative version

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

i need to turn the following recursive code into an iterative version and my mind is fried. i feel like im missing something obvious. any help is appreciated.

```
public static int computeRecursive(int n){
    if(n <= 1){
        return n;
    }
    else{
        return 2 * computeRecursive(n-2) + computeRecursive(n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: `return ((1<<n)+1)/3;`  :)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to an iterative fibonacci series, where you hold the initial two values of your function `f()` in two variables `a` and `b`. Then compute the result for the current `N` off of those previous two results:

```
public static int f(int n) {
    if ( n <= 1 ) { 
        return n; 
    }

    int result = 0; 
    int a = 0, // f(0) = 0
        b = 1; // f(1) = 1

    // start iteration at n=2 because we already have f(0) and f(1)
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        // f(n) = 2 * f(n-2) + f(n-1)
        result = 2 * a + b;

        // f(n-2) = f(n-1)
        a = b;
        // f(n-1) = f(n)
        b = result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @nachok I was more interested in the problem than whether it was homework or not. It isn't my responsibility to be the OP's moral conscience.

Comment: Hunter, the problem is that in that way i think you are not helping him/her doing his/her homework

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion both recursive and iterative solutions are weak if you can just apply your maths skills and work out the formula.

In this case we have: f(n) = (2 ** n -(-1) ** n)/3. Bellow is how you work it out.

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 1
f(n) = f(n-1) + 2 * f(n-2)

So the polynomial for this recurrence is:
r ** 2 = r + 2

If you sole that you will get the values of r as r1 =−1 and r2 =2

So the solution to the recurrence is on the form:
f(n) = c1 ∗ r1 ** n + c2 ∗ r2 ** n

To work out the values for c1 and c2 constants  just use the initial condition f(0) = 0 and f(1) = 1 and you will get
c1 = -1/3 and c2 = 1/3

So the final formula for your iteration is
f(n) = (-1 * (-1) ** n + 2 ** n)/3 = (2 ** n -(-1) ** n)/3.
```

Once you know the formula implementing it in java or any other language is easy.

```
public static int f(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? n: (Math.pow(2,n) - Math.pow(-1, n)) / 3;
}
```

Hope it helped

Comment: sorry I don't get the `f(n) = f(n-1) = 2 * f(n-2)`

Comment: Sorry I meant `f(n-1) + 2 * f(n-2). I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can may be try the below code. It is similar to fibonacci series.

```
public static int computeRecursive(int n){
int a[]=new int[n];
a[0]=1; a[1]=1;
for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
    a[i]=2*a[i-2]+a[i-1];
}
return a[n-1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed!